# JS - Deleting a child object of an object in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, loops

So it's a social media comments thing, with two parent comments, and `comment#2` has two child comments.

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "content": "Impressive! Though it seems the drag feature could be improved. But overall it looks incredible. You've nailed the design and the responsiveness at various breakpoints works really well.",
    "createdAt": "1 month ago",
    "score": 12,
    "user": {
        "image": {
            "png": "./images/avatars/image-amyrobson.png",
            "webp": "./images/avatars/image-amyrobson.webp"
        },
        "username": "amyrobson"
    },
    "replies": []
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "content": "Woah, your project looks awesome! How long have you been coding for? I'm still new, but think I want to dive into React as well soon. Perhaps you can give me an insight on where I can learn React? Thanks!",
    "createdAt": "2 weeks ago",
    "score": 5,
    "user": {
        "image": {
            "png": "./images/avatars/image-maxblagun.png",
            "webp": "./images/avatars/image-maxblagun.webp"
        },
        "username": "maxblagun"
    },
    "replies": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "content": "If you're still new, I'd recommend focusing on the fundamentals of HTML, CSS, and JS before considering React. It's very tempting to jump ahead but lay a solid foundation first.",
            "createdAt": "1 week ago",
            "score": 4,
            "replyingTo": "maxblagun",
            "user": {
                "image": {
                    "png": "./images/avatars/image-ramsesmiron.png",
                    "webp": "./images/avatars/image-ramsesmiron.webp"
                },
                "username": "ramsesmiron"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "content": "I couldn't agree more with this. Everything moves so fast and it always seems like everyone knows the newest library/framework. But the fundamentals are what stay constant.",
            "createdAt": "2 days ago",
            "score": 2,
            "replyingTo": "ramsesmiron",
            "user": {
                "image": {
                    "png": "./images/avatars/image-juliusomo.png",
                    "webp": "./images/avatars/image-juliusomo.webp"
                },
                "username": "juliusomo"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

]

I'm trying to figure out how to delete a child comment and return the array in the same *parent>child* set up.

Right now, on clicking the *delete* button on a comment I run a function that loops through the parent comments to filter out any parent comment that matches the ID of the comment that was clicked

```
    let filteredComments = [];

function handleClick(e) {
    setLoading(true);
    for (let i = 0; i < comments.length; i++) {
        if (comments[i].id !== Number(e.target.id)) {
            filteredComments = [...filteredComments, comments[i]];
        }
    }

    console.log(filteredComments);
    // setComments(...comments, filteredComments);
    setTimeout(() => {
        setLoading(false);
    }, 1000);
}
```

And that returns the an identical array to the original *data.json* comments from way up above. The comment I'm trying to delete is *id4* and is a child comment. I've tried a dozen different ways to loop through the child comments but I can't figure out how to only return child comments that don't match the selected comment id and return the object in the same `parent>child` way (at one point I got it to return an array with the child comment right next to the parent comments which would mess up mapping the comments to the page).

The last thing I tried was looping through the parent comments, pushing those to the filtered array, then loop through the child comments of any comments within the filtered array.

```
    let filteredComments = [];

function handleClick(e) {
    setLoading(true);
    for (let i = 0; i < comments.length; i++) {
        if (comments[i].id !== Number(e.target.id)) {
            filteredComments = [...filteredComments, comments[i]];
        }
    }


    if (comments[i].replies.length !== 0) {
        for (let k = 0; k < comments[i].replies.length; k++) {
            if (comments[i].replies[k].id !== Number(e.target.id)) {
                filteredComments = [
                    ...filteredComments,
                    comments[i].replies[k],
                ];
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(filteredComments);
    // setComments(...comments, filteredComments);
    setTimeout(() => {
        setLoading(false);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case there's a deeper level of replies (I added comment ID:5), this code should recursively handle the deletion:

```js
const comments = [{
    "id": 1,
    "content": "Impressive! Though it seems the drag feature could be improved. But overall it looks incredible. You've nailed the design and the responsiveness at various breakpoints works really well.",
    "createdAt": "1 month ago",
    "score": 12,
    "user": {
      "image": {
        "png": "./images/avatars/image-amyrobson.png",
        "webp": "./images/avatars/image-amyrobson.webp"
      },
      "username": "amyrobson"
    },
    "replies": []
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "content": "Woah, your project looks awesome! How long have you been coding for? I'm still new, but think I want to dive into React as well soon. Perhaps you can give me an insight on where I can learn React? Thanks!",
    "createdAt": "2 weeks ago",
    "score": 5,
    "user": {
      "image": {
        "png": "./images/avatars/image-maxblagun.png",
        "webp": "./images/avatars/image-maxblagun.webp"
      },
      "username": "maxblagun"
    },
    "replies": [{
        "id": 3,
        "content": "If you're still new, I'd recommend focusing on the fundamentals of HTML, CSS, and JS before considering React. It's very tempting to jump ahead but lay a solid foundation first.",
        "createdAt": "1 week ago",
        "score": 4,
        "replyingTo": "maxblagun",
        "user": {
          "image": {
            "png": "./images/avatars/image-ramsesmiron.png",
            "webp": "./images/avatars/image-ramsesmiron.webp"
          },
          "username": "ramsesmiron"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "content": "I couldn't agree more with this. Everything moves so fast and it always seems like everyone knows the newest library/framework. But the fundamentals are what stay constant.",
        "createdAt": "2 days ago",
        "score": 2,
        "replyingTo": "ramsesmiron",
        "user": {
          "image": {
            "png": "./images/avatars/image-juliusomo.png",
            "webp": "./images/avatars/image-juliusomo.webp"
          },
          "username": "juliusomo"
        },
        "replies": [{
          "id": 5,
          "content": "Even deeper comment",
          "replyingTo": "juliusomo",
          "createdAt": "3 month ago",
          "score": 80,
          "user": {
            "image": {
              "png": "./images/avatars/image-somebody.png",
              "webp": "./images/avatars/image-somebody.webp"
            },
            "username": "somebody"
          },
          "replies": []
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
]



function deleteComment(id, arr) {
  arr.forEach(function(item, index) {
    if (item.id == id) {
      arr.splice(index, 1)
    } else if (item.replies && item.replies.length > 0) {
      deleteComment(id, item.replies)
    }
  })
}

deleteComment(5, comments)

console.log(comments)
```

Comment: Hey this worked! I'm guessing "deleteComment(e.target.id, comments)" the "comments" part of that is updating the state as well without bringing in "setComments" since it's properly updating?

Comment: that will initialize the function passing it the entire array; later it will call itself here: `deleteComment(id, item.replies)` passing it the "replies" branch, when found inside a comment. The fact that it's updating itself (if I am not wrong) is intrinsic, javascript objects are always passed by reference, and arrays in javascript are technically objects (an explanation: https://flexiple.com/javascript/javascript-pass-by-reference-or-value)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are only using this to delete comments, and that there is only one level of replies.

All you need to do is locate the `replies` array and find the matching index within that array that requires deleting. Then use `splice` to delete it.

`reduce` is used to find a match, and return the replies and index when the match is found. The accumulator `a` is set to the match, or if no match is found, the accumulator is unaltered.

```js
const data = [{"id":1,"content":"Impressive! Though it seems the drag feature could be improved. But overall it looks incredible. You've nailed the design and the responsiveness at various breakpoints works really well.","createdAt":"1 month ago","score":12,"user":{"image":{"png":"./images/avatars/image-amyrobson.png","webp":"./images/avatars/image-amyrobson.webp"},"username":"amyrobson"},"replies":[]},{"id":2,"content":"Woah, your project looks awesome! How long have you been coding for? I'm still new, but think I want to dive into React as well soon. Perhaps you can give me an insight on where I can learn React? Thanks!","createdAt":"2 weeks ago","score":5,"user":{"image":{"png":"./images/avatars/image-maxblagun.png","webp":"./images/avatars/image-maxblagun.webp"},"username":"maxblagun"},"replies":[{"id":3,"content":"If you're still new, I'd recommend focusing on the fundamentals of HTML, CSS, and JS before considering React. It's very tempting to jump ahead but lay a solid foundation first.","createdAt":"1 week ago","score":4,"replyingTo":"maxblagun","user":{"image":{"png":"./images/avatars/image-ramsesmiron.png","webp":"./images/avatars/image-ramsesmiron.webp"},"username":"ramsesmiron"}},{"id":4,"content":"I couldn't agree more with this. Everything moves so fast and it always seems like everyone knows the newest library/framework. But the fundamentals are what stay constant.","createdAt":"2 days ago","score":2,"replyingTo":"ramsesmiron","user":{"image":{"png":"./images/avatars/image-juliusomo.png","webp":"./images/avatars/image-juliusomo.webp"},"username":"juliusomo"}}]}]

const idToDelete = 4

const {replies, index} = data.reduce((a, {replies}, index) => (
  index = replies.findIndex(({id}) => id===idToDelete), 
  index!==-1 ? {replies, index} : a), undefined)

replies.splice(index, 1)

console.log(data)
```

Comment: So I'm not too familiar with reduce and tried to slot this into the function, changing "data" to "comments" (the state with the data in it) and "idToDelete" to "e.target.id".

I'm getting the error "Cannot destructure property 'replies' of 'comments.reduce(...)' as it is undefined."

I tried throwing it into the for loop and changing comments.reduce to comments[i].reduce but that only returns an empty array.

Comment: @Ninety9Balloons if you get that error, it means there was no match. My code was expecting the id as a number - perhaps you were specifying it as a string? If you change `id===idToDelete` to `id==idToDelete`, it will be allow you to specify the id as a string or number.